# Disable read only fields in the response after posting the data

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

My model:

```
class NewsID(models.Model):
    pass

class News(models.Model):
    newsId=models.ForeignKey(NewsID,related_name = 'News', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lang_code=models.CharField(max_length=2)
    headline=models.CharField(max_length=100)

class DefaultLanguage(models.Model):
    news_id  = models.ForeignKey(NewsID,related_name = 'default', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    defaultLanguage_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
```

My serializer:

```
class NewsSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin,serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=News
        fields=('lang_code','headline')

class DefaultLanguageSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin,serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DefaultLanguage
        fields = ('news_id  ','defaultLanguage_id ')
        read_only_fields = ['news_id  ','defaultLanguage_id ']

class NewsIDSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin,serializers.ModelSerializer):
    News = NewsSerializer(many=True)
    default_language = serializers.CharField(max_length=2,write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = NewsID
        fields = ('id','News','default_language')
```

I want the response as below after posting :

```
{
      "id": 10,
      "News": [
        {
          "lang_code": "en",
          "headline": "Breaking news"
        }
      ],
      "default_language": "en"
    }
```

Now my response looks as below:

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "News": [
    {
      "lang_code": "en",
      "headline": "Breaking news"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now my response is having news_id and defaultLanguage_id (read only fields) I don't want the response with read only fields after posting. How to achieve this using Django?

Comment: plz share the response that you are getting

Comment: I have added my response. Please have a look.

Comment: Update your model `NewsID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your serializer from

```
class NewsIDSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin,serializers.ModelSerializer):
    News = NewsSerializer(many=True)
    default = DefaultLanguageSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    default_language = serializers.CharField(max_length=2,write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = NewsID
        fields = ('id','News','default','default_language')
```

To

```
class NewsIDSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin,serializers.ModelSerializer):
    News = NewsSerializer(many=True)
    default_language = serializers.CharField(max_length=2)

    class Meta:
        model = NewsID
        fields = ('id','News','default_language')
```

It will work as you expected.

Comment: Its working. But default_language is not coming in my response.I have edited my response in the code